# codeigniter controller class methodology?

Tags: php, codeigniter, model-view-controller

My problem is when I run the controller in the wamp server it will go to posts class and start executing the index function but how that happens ?
If I change the function name that won't work - how is that possible? Can you explain the procedure behind this?

```
class posts extends CI_Controller {
    function index(){
        $this->load->model('post');
        $data['posts'] = $this->post->get_posts();
        $this->load->view('post_index',$data);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you use the url as `baseurl/post` ?

Comment: read this https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/tutorial/static_pages.html

Comment: only thing i changed was the default controller in routes.php to
posts.php ,, and this is how i run 
http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.2/index.php/
and my controller gets executed with the function wt if i want to execute 
different function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In CI if the controller has index function then it automatically loads index method . Please read it here 
https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html